# CSRF token in Vue.js Storefront in Shopware 6

Tags: vue.js, csrf, shopware

I am using a custom instance of Vue.js in the storefront. But I’m having some issues with adding items to the cart. Or any API calls for that instance. I need a CSRF token for API call, but I have no idea how to retrieve this token from inside my Vue.js storefront, because I’m not using twig. Is there a way to get this token inside a Vue storefront?

In the twig files you can do something like this:

```html
{% block page_product_detail_buy_form_inner_csrf %}
    {{ sw_csrf('frontend.checkout.line-item.add') }}
{% endblock %}
```

But inside vue you can't use code like this. Is there a way to achieve this in my Vue storefront?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to print out the value of this magic constant in your HTML page and pass it to VueJs:

```
CsrfPlaceholderHandler::CSRF_PLACEHOLDER
```

See
https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/d6c853ca3b6b167d61d70e6329f4fcface5c5245/src/Storefront/Framework/Csrf/CsrfPlaceholderHandler.php#L13

The CSRF handler seems to replace this by the real CSRF token.